# Facing screen freeze (sort of?) in IE11, WIndows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, freeze

While using an internal web application running under IE11 compatibility mode, after clicking on a link, the link portion gets freezed & keeps showing up as topmost layer on the screen. I'm unable to find the exact word to describe it.

Refer the image below:[image: Screen Portion Freeze (Highlighted in red)]

It persists screen lock cycles, even after cleaning IE off memory. But it gets resolved after log off, restart.
What & why could it be ?

Comment: "While using an internal web application" - please ask your IT department.

Comment: @DavidPostill: It isn't a feature of web application, per say. And I'm a part of the IT team. I asked myself again & again, then binged it, SOed it. Then I asked the question here. Please explain now. :)

Comment: How can we know what your internal web application does? Voting to close (sorry) but this is off topic.

Comment: But it is not specific to application - IT PERSISTS EVEN AFTER APP & IE HAVE BEEN CLOSED! Infact I wonder, how can it be replicated or achieved?